# How to use Liberation fonts in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

I have the following snipped of code

```
\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[DejaVu Sans]

\starttext

Test text

Тестовый текст

\stoptext
```

And this works great. ConTeXt compiles it and the font is correct. But if I change font to

```
\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[Liberation Sans]

\starttext

Test text

Тестовый текст

\stoptext
```

then result will be of wrong font and russian text is not rendered.

The font names are taken from output of `fc-list` program (Linux).
ConTeXt installed from texlive, version is

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.60
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2013.05.28 00:36
```

Comment: I use ConteXt in Windows and i dont have problem like that, it's ok.

Comment: Check your corresponding .log file. Also, you probably don't have Liberation Sans installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ConTeXt MkIV does not rely on system font mechanism to get the font name. So the information returned by `fc-cache` is useless. Instead use the `mtx-fonts` script to find the name of the font.

1. Run

   ```
   mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern=liberation --all
   ```

   which gives

   ```
   liberationmono                   liberationmono                   LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
   liberationmonobold               liberationmonobold               LiberationMono-Bold.ttf
   liberationmonobolditalic         liberationmonobolditalic         LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf
   liberationmonoitalic             liberationmonoitalic             LiberationMono-Italic.ttf
   liberationmononormal             liberationmono                   LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
   liberationsans                   liberationsans                   LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
   liberationsansbold               liberationsansbold               LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
   liberationsansbolditalic         liberationsansbolditalic         LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
   liberationsansitalic             liberationsansitalic             LiberationSans-Italic.ttf
   liberationsansnarrow             liberationsansnarrow             LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf
   liberationsansnarrowbold         liberationsansnarrowbold         LiberationSansNarrow-Bold.ttf
   liberationsansnarrowbolditalic   liberationsansnarrowbolditalic   LiberationSansNarrow-BoldItalic.ttf
   liberationsansnarrowitalic       liberationsansnarrowitalic       LiberationSansNarrow-Italic.ttf
   liberationsansnarrownormal       liberationsansnarrowitalic       LiberationSansNarrow-Italic.ttf
   liberationsansnormal             liberationsans                   LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
   liberationserif                  liberationserif                  LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
   liberationserifbold              liberationserifbold              LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf
   liberationserifbolditalic        liberationserifbolditalic        LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
   liberationserifitalic            liberationserifitalic            LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf
   liberationserifnormal            liberationserifitalic            LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf
   ```
2. If the above does not list the fonts, regenerate the font database.

   ```
    mtxrun --script font --reload --force
   ```
3. If the fonts are still not listed, check the value of `OSFONTDIR` using

   ```
   mtxrun --expand-var OSFONTDIR
   ```

   You can force the search path using

   ```
    OSFONTDIR=/path/to/font mtxrun --script font --reload --force
   ```

Comment: I am not getting similar list for liberation but I am getting same list for `--pattern=dejavu`. Liberation fonts are installed and there is TTF files in `/usr/share/fonts/liberation-fonts` just like DejaVu has in `/usr/share/fonts/dejavu`

Comment: Perhaps the fonts were installed after ConTeXt. Run `mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force` and try again.

Comment: Must I run it under `root`?

Comment: It did not help, and I was get this warnings when run `mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force`  http://bpaste.net/show/Rgd4ZF5GAaGuoLssbCsC/

Comment: @s9gf4ult Also try forcing the search path: ``OSFONTDIR=/path/to/font mtxrun --script fonts --reload``

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/zE27AG133mPU8fZdmZ65/ it does not help.

Comment: `mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern=libertation --all` does not show anything, but file `/home/razor/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/0399a8df3aef8d154781d0a9c2b8e28d/fonts/data/names.tma` contains `liberationsans` and context renders font as expected. This answer must be fixed to be confirmed.

Comment: @s9gf4ult Could be just a typo: The font is spelled “liberation”, without the extra “t”. Btw you can use wildcards, e.g. ``--pattern=liber*`` will show Liberation and Libertine, if installed.

Comment: It was a typo. `mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern='liberat*' --all` shows all I need.