# Why does ConTeXt keep telling me "source file is not found"?

Tags: fonts, errors, context

I can't seem to make ConTeXt work with system fonts.  Let's take this simple example from [another question on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151445/how-to-use-liberation-fonts-in-context) :

```
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[liberationsans]
\starttext
Test text
\stoptext
```

It won't compile :

```
$ context aa.tex

mtx-context     | run 1: luatex --fmt="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en" --jobname="aa" --lua="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./aa" --c:input="./aa" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.81.0 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (rev 5350) 
 \write18 enabled.

system          > callbacks > not registering frozen 'find_format_file'
open source     > 1 > 1 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-yes.mkiv

ConTeXt  ver: 2015.10.09 21:28 MKIV beta  fmt: 2015.10.21  int: english/english

system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > 2 > 2 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
close source    > 2 > 2 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
system          > files > jobname 'aa', input './aa', result 'aa'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > 2 > 3 > /data/LédiFrance/catalogues/automatic/aa.tex
resolvers       > modules > 'simplefonts' is loaded
open source     > 3 > 4 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simplefonts/t-simplefonts.mkiv
loading         > ConTeXt User Module / Simplefonts
resolvers       > lua > loading file '/opt/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simplefonts/t-simplefonts.lua' succeeded
close source    > 3 > 4 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simplefonts/t-simplefonts.mkiv
fonts           > defining > source file 'LiberationSans-Regular.ttf' is not found
backend         > xmp > using file '/opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/lpdf-pdx.xml'
pages           > flushing realpage 1, userpage 1
close source    > 2 > 4 > /data/LédiFrance/catalogues/automatic/aa.tex
close source    > 1 > 4 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-yes.mkiv

!LuaTeX error: cannot find OpenType font file for reading ()
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

If I understand correctly, it fails on `defining > source file 'LiberationSans-Regular.ttf' is not found`.  Yet said file is found by `mtx-run` (and has read access for all) :

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=Liberation

liberationmono              liberationmono              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
liberationmonobold          liberationmonobold          /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-Bold.ttf
liberationmonobolditalic    liberationmonobolditalic    /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf
liberationmonoitalic        liberationmonoitalic        /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-Italic.ttf
liberationmononormal        liberationmono              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
liberationmonoregular       liberationmono              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
liberationsans              liberationsans              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
liberationsansbold          liberationsansbold          /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
liberationsansbolditalic    liberationsansbolditalic    /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
liberationsansitalic        liberationsansitalic        /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Italic.ttf
liberationsansnormal        liberationsans              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
liberationsansregular       liberationsans              /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
liberationserif             liberationserif             /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
liberationserifbold         liberationserifbold         /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf
liberationserifbolditalic   liberationserifbolditalic   /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
liberationserifitalic       liberationserifitalic       /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf
liberationserifnormal       liberationserif             /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
liberationserifregular      liberationserif             /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
```

What am I missing ?

(And BTW, I understand from the answer to the question listed above that `simplefonts` should be fed with the output of `mtx-run`, but *which column* ?)

Comment: Which ConTeXt version are you using? TL2016 bet? Both, TL2015 and current beta (2015.10.09 21:28 MKIV beta), work flawlessly with your MWE. Maybe your paths are mixed up.

Comment: @DG' : Right, but which paths ?  I assumed that if `mtxrun` found the font, `context` should find it as well ?  OSFONTDIR is set to `/usr/share/fonts;/home/[myuser]/.fonts`, and I'm using the version mentioned in the log.

Comment: Ah, no time to test further but there is no error when I link the font into $HOME/.fonts…  More tests later.

Comment: Why don't you paste your update as an answer?

Comment: @DG' : I didn't post the workaround at first, so it wasn't a solution, but with it you're right, it's better in an answer (as pathetic as it might be… :) ).

Comment: But maybe, just maybe, you should use TL2015 or [standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) for production . . .

Comment: Well, actually I did follow these instructions (system-wide installation)…  Indeed it installed current beta.

Comment: I've been having a similar issue since updating my standalone installation to `2015.10.09`.  It only crops up intermittently for me.  If I just run things again, everything goes smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

LuaTeX (or rather `kpsepath`) does not search fonts directories recursively. even with `OSFONTDIR="/usr/share/fonts//"` (note two trailing slashes) as [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209705/context-system-font-search-path). It didn't help, although `kpsewhich --var-value=OSFONTDIR` gives the expected path.

Use this as a workaround:

```
mkdir $HOME/.fonts
export OSFONTDIR="$OSFONTDIR:$HOME/.fonts"
for ii in $(find /usr/share/fonts -name "*.ttf") $(find /usr/share/fonts -name "*.otf"); do ln -s $ii ~/.fonts/; done
```

This creates the `$HOME/.fonts`, directory, add it to `OSFONTDIR` and links recursively all `otf` and `ttf` files from `/usr/share/fonts` into `$HOME/.fonts`.

---

A similar approach:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.fonts
mkdir $HOME/.fonts
cd $HOME/.fonts
for i in $(echo $OSFONTDIR | sed -e 's/:/ /g') ; do
  for j in $(find $i -type f); do
    ln -s $j .;
  done;
done
```

The script uses the current `$OSFONTDIR` value and recurses through the directories to link all font files into `$HOME/.fonts`. Then update (e.g., `$HOME/.bashrc`):

```
OSFONTDIR=$HOME/.fonts
export OSFONTDIR
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You did run `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` every time you changed $OSFONTDIR or the fonts or anything else, didn't you?

Comment: I can't say I was *that* systematic, but I think I did it often enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Liberation on my system, so I can't test, but this should work. The functionality of the module `simplefonts` has been integrated into the core of context, so you don't need it anymore. And the argument it needs is not in the font script of `mtxrun`, it's the family name of your font. So in your case, you should try:

```
\definefontfamily [test] [sans] [Liberation Sans]
\setupbodyfont [test,ss,12pt]
\starttext
Test text
\stoptext
```

Comment: So finally I should use the font name as given by `fc-list`, as opposite to what is explained in the question I mention above ?

Comment: Anyway, your sample gives exactly the same error…  It's not a problem with Liberation itself, actually I choose Liberation for the question because it's quite common but I first triggered this issue on a OTF font from Dafont.

Comment: I can only refer you to [a message](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/88646/) from the list in which Wolfgang (the guy who wrote this mechanism) explains it. So yes, the answer that Aditya gave in the question you mention appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Actually it makes things even more confusing : Wolfgang says "The family name is shown when you use the info option", but there is no mention of "Liberation Sans" when doing this (only "liberationsans"), yet this is indeed what appears in (most) GUI software, and he mentions in his next message it should be the name to use…

Comment: I never said it wasn't confusing :-). As much as I love this new font mechanism, I have at times given up and written a good old-fashioned typescript because I couldn't make it find the font I wanted to use. And I'm not a huge fan of this idea of making system fonts available. I have disabled searching my system font directories (too much interference with similar fonts and names); when I want to use a font with context, I copy it over to my local texmf tree. That way, I have more control.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion, it may be worth having a think about.  My posts are still awaiting moderation but I've asked my questions on the list you linked.